# Angular2 resolver returns undefined when the data service console logs the data fine

Tags: angular, http, asynchronous, resolve, resolver

I am trying to pre-fetch data before displaying the component by using angular2's resolver.

so in my data.service.ts: 
I have a function that retrieves an employee detail:

```
  getEmployee(id:string) {
      let headers = new Headers();
      this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
      this.employeeUrl = 'someurl/property?'+'employee_number='+id;
      return this._http.get(this.employeeUrl, {headers})
        .map(resp => resp.json())
        .do(data => console.log('employee: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))

//this returns a json log in console.
```

In my employee-detail-resolver.service.ts file i have set up a resolver like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class EmployeeDetailResolver implements Resolve<IEmployee>{
  employee: IEmployee;

  constructor( private _dataService: DataService, private router: Router ) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<IEmployee> {
    console.log('returning resolved data');
    let id = route.params['id'];
    return this._dataService.getEmployee(id)
      .map(employee => {
        if(employee) {
        return employee;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/employees']);
        return null;
      }
    });

}

}
```

and I try to get the data from the resolver in my employee-detail.component.ts file like this:

```
export class EmployeeDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  busy: Subscription;
  employee: IEmployee;
  id: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router,
              private _dataService: DataService
              ) {

    }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data
      .subscribe((data: {employee: IEmployee}) => {
        this.employee = data.employee;
      })
     console.log("testing employee detail:", this.route.snapshot.data['data']);
  // this logs undefined in the console
  }

  onBack(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/employees']);
  }
}
```

I know I'm getting the data accurately because I see it in the console, and my template with *ngIf="employee" loads with no data. I don't understand why my component returns undefined value..

my routing module looks like this:

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {path: 'employee/:id', component: EmployeeDetailComponent,
      resolve: {
       employee: EmployeeDetailResolver
      }
    },
    {path: 'employees', component: EmployeesListComponent},
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/employees', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

export const Routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, {useHash: true});
```

I have it declared as a provider in my app.module.ts:

```
  providers: [ DataService, EmployeeDetailResolver ],
```

can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong??

FIX: 
in employee-detail.component.ts
I changed to

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.employee = this.route.snapshot.data['employee'][0];
    console.log("working?",this.employee[0]);
  }
```

and now the data displays every time I click!
It was snapshot!!!

Answer (score 3):

Code that depends on data from async calls needs to be executed within callbacks that are called when data arrives:

```
this.route.data
  .subscribe((data: {employee: IEmployee}) => {
    this.employee = data.employee;
    console.log("testing employee detail:", data['data']);

  })
  // code here is executed before async data was received
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I have a resolver that prefetches data. In my routing module, I have the resolver defined:  `{path: 'employee/:id', component: EmployeeDetailComponent,
      resolve: {
       employee: EmployeeDetailResolver
      }
    },` doesn't it tell my employee-detail component that the resolver needs to resolve the data first before it can run any of its own methods?

Comment: I see what you mean. Didn't look close enough.

Comment: Actually I'd also expect `route.snapshot.data` to actually contain the value when the component is created, but in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard they also only use `this.route.data.subscribe(...)`

Comment: Sorry., I don't quite get how `route.snapshot.data` can fix the problem...Could you show me how you would change it using route.snapshot.data?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update the answer. The way it is currently in my answer is how it's demonstrated in the docs. I don't know why just reading from `snapshot` doesn't work. As I said, I would also expect it but obviously it seems not to work and the docs don't mention it either.

Comment: Hi! You were actually right! `snapshot`worked! I changed my employee-detail.component's ngOnInit function to this: `this.employee = this.route.snapshot.data['employee'][0];` and it works now!!